# Ubuntu 19.10/20.04 keeps asking for password in some random wifi networks

Tags: wireless, network-manager, 19.10

After upgrade from 19.04 to 19.10 some of wifi networks I had no issues with previously, now keeps asking for password and do not connect even if correct one is typed.

UPDATES:

1. The issue remains in 20.04.
2. It still connects well using 18.04 Live USB boot.
3. It manages to connect to other protected networks at home or coffee shop using this machine on 19.10 and 20.04.
4. It manages to connect to the same router to non-protected WiFi network.
5. 20.04 Live connects well to the same protected wifi using other machine.

Funnily some other wifi networks works well like before. Any ideas?

**The card info**

```
*-network                 
   description: Wireless interface
   product: BCM4350 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:3a:00.0
   logical name: wlp58s0
   version: 08
   serial: 30:52:cb:80:4a:37
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=brcmfmac driverversion=7.35.180.119 firmware=01-e791c176 ip=10.3.0.19 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:136 memory:dc400000-dc407fff memory:dc000000-dc3fffff
```

**lspci -knn | grep Net -A3 (output)**

```
3a:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4350 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a3] (rev 08)
    Subsystem: Dell BCM4350 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1028:0023]
    Kernel driver in use: brcmfmac
    Kernel modules: brcmfmac
3b:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525APCI Express Card Reader [10ec:525a] (rev 01)
```

**Network manager log**

```
spal. 28 15:52:28 : <info>  [1572270748.9800] device (wlp58s0): Activation: starting connection 'ROCKITmembers(2G)' (0caaa7d0-e2b2-47be-9442-bef0dd5303fd)
spal. 28 15:52:28 : <info>  [1572270748.9819] device (wlp58s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
spal. 28 15:52:28 : <info>  [1572270748.9824] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
spal. 28 15:52:28 : <info>  [1572270748.9845] device (wlp58s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
spal. 28 15:52:28 : <info>  [1572270748.9857] device (wlp58s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'ROCKITmembers(2G)' has security, but secrets are required.
spal. 28 15:52:28 : <info>  [1572270748.9859] device (wlp58s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
spal. 28 15:52:32 : <info>  [1572270752.0135] device (wlp58s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
spal. 28 15:52:32 : <info>  [1572270752.0162] device (wlp58s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
spal. 28 15:52:32 : <info>  [1572270752.0189] device (wlp58s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'ROCKITmembers(2G)' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
spal. 28 15:52:32 : <info>  [1572270752.0191] Config: added 'ssid' value 'ROCKITmembers(2G)'
spal. 28 15:52:32 : <info>  [1572270752.0192] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
spal. 28 15:52:32 : <info>  [1572270752.0193] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-80:86400'
spal. 28 15:52:32 : <info>  [1572270752.0194] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256 FT-PSK'
spal. 28 15:52:32 : <info>  [1572270752.0194] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
spal. 28 15:52:32 : <info>  [1572270752.0195] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
spal. 28 15:52:32 : <info>  [1572270752.1078] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> associating
spal. 28 15:52:32 : <info>  [1572270752.1078] device (p2p-dev-wlp58s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> associating
spal. 28 15:52:34 : <info>  [1572270754.9259] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> 4-way handshake
spal. 28 15:52:34 : <info>  [1572270754.9260] device (p2p-dev-wlp58s0): supplicant management interface state: associating -> 4-way handshake
spal. 28 15:52:44 : <warn>  [1572270764.9015] sup-iface[0x558274d6c920,wlp58s0]: connection disconnected (reason -2)
spal. 28 15:52:44 : <info>  [1572270764.9049] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> disconnected
spal. 28 15:52:44 : <info>  [1572270764.9093] device (wlp58s0): Activation: (wifi) disconnected during association, asking for new key
spal. 28 15:52:44 : <info>  [1572270764.9095] device (wlp58s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'supplicant-disconnect', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
spal. 28 15:52:44 : <info>  [1572270764.9107] device (p2p-dev-wlp58s0): supplicant management interface state: 4-way handshake -> disconnected
spal. 28 15:52:47 : <info>  [1572270767.7116] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> inactive
spal. 28 15:52:47 : <info>  [1572270767.7118] device (p2p-dev-wlp58s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> inactive
spal. 28 15:52:49 : <info>  [1572270769.1482] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: inactive -> scanning
spal. 28 15:52:49 : <info>  [1572270769.1483] device (p2p-dev-wlp58s0): supplicant management interface state: inactive -> scanning
spal. 28 15:52:49 : <info>  [1572270769.3299] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> inactive
spal. 28 15:52:49 : <info>  [1572270769.3299] device (p2p-dev-wlp58s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> inactive
spal. 28 15:52:50 : <info>  [1572270770.9128] device (wlp58s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
spal. 28 15:52:50 : <info>  [1572270770.9141] device (wlp58s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
spal. 28 15:52:50 : <info>  [1572270770.9150] device (wlp58s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'ROCKITmembers(2G)' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
spal. 28 15:52:50 : <info>  [1572270770.9151] Config: added 'ssid' value 'ROCKITmembers(2G)'
spal. 28 15:52:50 : <info>  [1572270770.9151] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
spal. 28 15:52:50 : <info>  [1572270770.9152] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-80:86400'
spal. 28 15:52:50 : <info>  [1572270770.9152] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256 FT-PSK'
spal. 28 15:52:50 : <info>  [1572270770.9152] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
spal. 28 15:52:50 : <info>  [1572270770.9152] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
spal. 28 15:52:50 : <info>  [1572270770.9857] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: inactive -> associating
spal. 28 15:52:50 : <info>  [1572270770.9858] device (p2p-dev-wlp58s0): supplicant management interface state: inactive -> associating
spal. 28 15:52:53 : <info>  [1572270773.0501] device (wlp58s0): disconnecting for new activation request.
spal. 28 15:52:53 : <info>  [1572270773.0503] device (wlp58s0): state change: config -> deactivating (reason 'new-activation', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
spal. 28 15:52:53 : <info>  [1572270773.0521] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTING
```

Comment: Would it help that you delete the wifi and the try to reconnect?

Comment: Tried many times. No difference. Looks that some wifis have something specific I cannot figure out.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 added the output.